# How do I remove typescript definition?

Tags: typescript, tsd

I found some definition were necessary for me. I tried to remove but I couldn't find the specify command. It's not like `npm` it has `uninstall` command can directly uninstall them, so I just remove the ones from `tsd.json` without typing `uninstall` command.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running `tsd reinstall --clean` will eliminate the definitions not found in `tsd.json`.

Please note that `tsd` is deprecated. Consider using [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) as your definitions package manager.

Here's how you can *uninstall* a definition package using *typings*

```
typings uninstall <name> [--save|--save-dev|--save-peer] [--ambient]
Options:
  [--save|-S]       Remove from "dependencies"
  [--save-dev|-D]   Remove from "devDependencies"
  [--save-peer|-P]  Remove from "peerDependencies"
  [--ambient|-A]    Remove from the ambient version of dependencies
    [-SA]           Remove from "ambientDependencies"
    [-DA]           Remove from "ambientDevDependencies"
Aliases: r, rm, remove, un
```